# How can I make this query return results when one isn't present?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgis

Poly1 is a bounding box that calculates the acreage of f1 and f2 that falls inside of its boundaries. How do I make this query return results if f1 is present, but f2 is not? Right now, if the bounding box only has f1 inside it, the query returns no results.

```
SELECT ST_Transform(poly1.the_geom,3857) AS the_geom_webmercator, 
       ST_AREA(ST_Union(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(f1.the_geom,poly1.the_geom),3857)))*.000247105381 AS acreage_of_1,
       ST_AREA(ST_Union(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(f2.the_geom,poly1.the_geom),3857)))*.000247105381 AS acreage_of_2
            FROM poly1 JOIN farmland f1 ON f1.polygon_type = 'A' AND
                                           st_intersects(f1.the_geom,poly1.the_geom)
                       JOIN farmland f2 ON f2.polygon_type = 'B'
            GROUP BY poly1.the_geom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a left outer join before the "farmland f2" statement.  The left outer join will keep all the rows, even if there are no matches in f2:

```
Select ST_Transform(poly1.the_geom,3857) as the_geom_webmercator, 
       ST_AREA(ST_Union(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(f1.the_geom,poly1.the_geom),3857)))*.000247105381 AS acreage_of_1,
       ST_AREA(ST_Union(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(f2.the_geom,poly1.the_geom),3857)))*.000247105381 AS acreage_of_2
FROM poly1 JOIN
     farmland f1
     ON f1.polygon_type = 'A' AND st_intersects(fp.the_geom,poly1.the_geom) **LEFT OUTER** JOIN
     farmland f2
     ON f2.polygon_type = 'B'
 group by poly1.the_geom
```